# Change osm bonus pack input file

Tags: openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am using osmbonuspack library in my project to find the route between a departure and a destination node and I want to save information related to the traversal time of the edges. So I keep a file which contains the nodes and edges of a specific city (OSM data). My problem is that for a specific route, osmbonuspack returns a road that doesn't agree with my file. I mean that when I search for two nodes of the route in my file, they exist, but there isn't an edge between them, while osmbonuspack has found an edge between them. 
I know that this may is happening because I keep information only for a city, so this edge in my file is probably split into more nodes and edges.
But is there any way that I can change an input file or url in osmbonuspack so that it searches for a route in my .osm file?

Answer (score 1):

No way: OSMBonusPack only provides access to online route services.

For offline routing using local map files, you can try [GraphHopper Android](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/android/index.md).